# WP nav menu bug

Tags: css, wordpress, html

I have used WP nav menu in my website. It works fine. I have added the sub link under the home link. But it is not properly displayed. Please refer the screenshot.
[image]

In the above image, "support our work" sub link is fine. But the Home sub link is not properly displayed. I need "News, Calendar, Like Us On FaceB" displays under the HOME link similar to "Support our work". Home Page does not accept the sub links.

Comment: could you post you css and html code

Comment: For menu display I have used the following code. "wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) );" This is not the css issue. Because if I add the sub menus to any other main menu it works fine. The Home link only does not support the sub menu.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a static page as home page it is possible.

Go to  Settings, Reading, Front page displays. Then select your "Front page", that will appear in the menu as the home link.

Then in **functions.php** of your theme add this code:

```
function my_page_menu_args( $args ) {
    $args['show_home'] = false; // Do not show 'home' link in the menu.
    return $args;
}
add_filter('wp_page_menu_args', 'my_page_menu_args', 1000);
```

In the menu, the subpages of the selected page, will now appear as submenu items.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `theme_location => 'secondary'`